# Create expanded/permuted dataframe from several lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very open to changing the title of the question if there's a clearer way to ask this.

I want to convert several lists into repeated columns of a dataframe. Somehow, between itertools and np.tile, I wasn't able to get the behavior I wanted.

Input:

```
list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = [a, b]
list_3 = [A, B]
```

Output:

```
col1  col2  col3
1     a     A
1     a     B
1     b     A
1     b     B
2     a     A
2     a     B
2     b     A
2     b     B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is I think what you're looking for:

```py
>>> pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(list_1, list_2, list_3))
   0  1  2
0  1  a  A
1  1  a  B
2  1  b  A
3  1  b  B
4  2  a  A
5  2  a  B
6  2  b  A
7  2  b  B
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient this would be with very large lists, but it is a possible approach to your problem.

```
list_1 = [1, 2]
list_2 = ['a', 'b']
list_3 = ['A', 'B']
indices = []
values = []

for i in list_1:
    for m in list_2:
        for n in list_3:
            indices.append(i)
            values.append([m,n])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=indices)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   0  1
1  a  A
1  a  B
1  b  A
1  b  B
2  a  A
2  a  B
2  b  A
2  b  B
```

Comment: Just saw Michael Delgado's answer. Looks better than mine.